# Yii2 - How to format the footer in my GridView?

Tags: gridview, yii2, footer

This is the code my GridView. I would like the footer to have the same format with its column. How do I do it? Thanks!

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'showFooter' => true,
'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','thousandSeparator' => ',','currencyCode' => 'PHP',],
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
        'attribute' =>'account_code',
        'footer' =>'Total',
        ],
        'account_name',
        [
        'attribute' =>'amount',
        'format' => 'currency',
        'footer' => Accounts::getTotal($dataProvider->models, 'amount'),
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
```

]);

[Picture of the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxULO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the prefix

```
 'footer' => 'PHP' . Accounts::getTotal($dataProvider->models, 'amount'),
```

and for thousand separator  you can use number_format

```
'footer' => 'PHP' .
       number_format (Accounts::getTotal($dataProvider->models, 'amount'), 2 , "." ,  "," )
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the thousandSeparator?